# How can I resolve "pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: PySide" when running Everpad in 15.04?

Tags: 15.04, everpad

When trying to run ever pad from the terminal I get the following error(s). Can anyone point me in the right direction for getting everpad up and runnning? Python 2.7 is installed on my system

Terminal output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/everpad", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3020, in <module>
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 614, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 920, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 807, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: PySide
```